# How to get data if data is not specified in date columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Below is my mysql Table structure.

```
   varchar(255)   int        varchar(255)
       /             \           |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |name     | b_date        | details   |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Raj     | 2020-09-11    | Mumbai    |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Kunal   | 2020-09-11    | Pune      |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Pooja   | 2020-09-11    | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Sam     | 2020-09-14    | nagpure   |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |  Alok   | 2020-09-14    | Nashik    |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Reema   | 2020-09-14    | Mumbai    |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | India     |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  | Kunal   | 2020-09-11    | Pune      |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
  |         |               | MH        |
  +---------+---------------+-----------+
```

I am using below query to fetch data date wise,

```
select_data = """SELECT name, details;
                 FROM {} WHERE b_date >= date('2020-09-14')
                 AND b_date < date('2020-09-14')
                 + INTERVAL 1 DAY""".format(table)
```

It gives me values as below,

```
    Sam   nagpure
    Alok  Nashik 
    Reema Mumbai
    Kunal Pune
```

However I need it like this

```
Sam   nagpure
      MH
      India
Alok  Nashik
      MH
      India 
Reema Mumbai
      MH
      India
Kunal Pune 
      MH
```

Not able able to figure out how to get values which is not having b_date values in columns.

I tried below code but that doesn't worked

```
select_data = """SELECT name, details;
             FROM {} WHERE b_date >= date('2020-09-14')
             AND b_date < date('2020-09-14')
             AND b_date IS NULL 
             + INTERVAL 1 DAY""".format(table)
```

Comment: how are you supposed to link sam to MH and India?

Comment: Your data seems to be posessional-dependent (like on the worksheet) whereas a table is unordered heap (relative rows ordering not exists). The task is unsolvable on shown storing structure.

Comment: I get it for all dates when I don't use `where` condition. However I get it for all the dates. I am just trying to get it for particular date. 
`select name, details from mytable;`

Comment: It is not possible to store the character '-' in an int field... => table structure is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changes in your schema: create a table to store your Details and a table to implement many-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE base (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    b_date TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE detail (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE base_detail (
    base_id INT,
    detail_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (base_id, detail_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BASE FOREIGN KEY (base_id) references base (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DETAIL FOREIGN KEY (detail_id) references detail(id)
) ENGINE INNODB;
```

Humble filling:

```
INSERT INTO base VALUES (1, "Alok", "2020-09-14");
INSERT INTO detail VALUES (1, "Nashik"), (2, "MH"), (3, "India");
INSERT INTO base_detail VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3);
```

Then the select you need would look like:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    base b
JOIN
    base_detail bd ON bd.base_id = b.id
JOIN detail d on d.id = bd.detail_id
WHERE
    b.b_date BETWEEN "2020-09-14" AND "2020-09-15"
;
```

Result:

```
id  name    b_date                  base_id detail_id   id  name
1   Alok    2020-09-14T00:00:00Z    1       1           1   Nashik
1   Alok    2020-09-14T00:00:00Z    1       2           2   MH
1   Alok    2020-09-14T00:00:00Z    1       3           3   India
```